# From Xamarin.iOS project : [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.ios

Hello Xamarin community,

It's been a complete day I'm facing this very common issue :

> 6.5.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.

This error occurs in my Xamarin.iOS project, where I added the NuGet package [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFirestore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFirestore/) (v1.4.2.1).

---

Here is my code :

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
    Database = Firestore.SharedInstance;

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

**CloudFirestoreiOS.cs**

```
public async Task < T > GetRandomItemAsync() {
    if (IsConnected) {
        try {
            var db = AppDelegate.Database;
            var myCollection = db.GetCollection("[COLLECTION_NAME]");

            var snapshots = await myCollection.GetDocumentsAsync();
            foreach(var snapshot in snapshots.Documents) {
                var documentContent = snapshot.Data;
                var fieldValue = documentContent["DOCUMENT_FIELD_NAME"] ? .ToString();
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    return null
}
```

"*Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend*" occurs at *GetDocumentsAsync()* method call.

This error says that :

> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment.

But I made an HTTP Request instead of using the iOS CloudFirestore NuGet and it works fine :

```
try {
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = client.GetAsync("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[MY_PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default)/documents/[COLLECTION_NAME]/[DOCUMENT_ID]").Result;
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var z = response.StatusCode;

} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

**Hence, this may be an CloudFirestore configuration problem**, and I don't know how to verify if Firestore.ShareInstance object is correctly initialized or not.

*Could you please first tell me how to do that ?*

---

### Things I've already tried

- Check GoogleService-Info.plist file (e.g. API_KEY, DATABASE_URL, PROJECT_ID)
- Deploy solution on a physical device
- Erase all content and settings of the Simulator
- Make an HTTP Request instead of using the iOS CloudFirestore NuGet
- Downgrade the iOS CloudFirestore NuGet, but solution was no more buildable
- Check this very good example [from Github](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents), but solution was not buildable even after having restored packages

### Things I must try

- I must try again this very good example [from Github](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents) in order to better understand where I'm wrong
- I must try to reproduce Cloud Firestore querying from a Xamarin.Android project

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you able to make http requests to any other test api? (icndb/ipinfo)

Answer (score 0):

I've really had a hard time on this case, but I've finally found a way to make it work !

Two things that might have finally helped :

- Calling CloudFirestore Task from the ViewModel failed every time until I implement a Command execution
- I force execution of my Task when loading my View (I still don't understand why, but when running my app : the first time my Task was called, I've always got the error)
- I don't use Firebase.SharedInstance anymore in the Xamarin.iOS project (this might explains above point)

**In Xamarin.Forms project**

```
public SandboxViewModel()
{
Product = new Product { ProductTitle = "THIS IS A NICE TITLE" };

GetOneProductCommand = new Command(async () => await GetOneProductAsync());

GetOneProductCommand.Execute(null);
}

private async Task GetOneProductAsync()
{
try
{
Product product = await DataStore.GetOneItem();

if (product != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(product.ProductTitle))
Product = new Product { ProductTitle = product.ProductTitle };
else
Product = new Product { ProductTitle = "THIS IS A NICE ERROR..." };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get products : {ex.Message}");
await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
}
}
```

**In Xamarin.iOS project**

```
public async Task<Product> GetOneItem()
{
Product product = new Product();
Firestore dbRef = Firestore.Create(Firebase.Core.App.DefaultInstance);

CollectionReference Products = dbRef.GetCollection("Products");

var snapshot = await Products.GetDocumentsAsync();

foreach (var doc in snapshot.Documents)
{
if (doc.Exists)
{
var documentContent = doc.Data;

if (documentContent != null)
product = new ShortUserProduct { ProductTitle = documentContent["ProductTitle"]?.ToString() };
else
product = null;
}
}

return product;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use again Firestore.SharedInstance and it appears that this was not the actual problem.